# Blazor web assembly. Clear input controls

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have built a small application in Blazor web assembly using MudBlazor. I have a method, `Clear()`, which basically clears MudTextFields upon calling. After 10 seconds, this method should be called. How and where should I call this method? As an example, I am using the following:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <MudField Label="Country" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Adornment="Adornment.End"     AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.CheckCircle"     AdornmentColor="Color.Success">@_Country</MudField>
</div>
```

c# code:

```
private void Clear()
{
    _Country = string.Empty;
}
```

I have to call this method for my code to work.

Comment: 10 seconds after what? Or maybe you mean "every 10 seconds"?

Comment: Basically there is a MudTextField which is bound with Barcode variable. When the user scan a barcode, this value is assigned to Barcode variable. On ENTER key pressed event which is a custom method a WebAPI method is called which return information of an object with Name, Address, Contact number and Country. This information is shown in other 4 MudTextFields. All is done ok. When information is shown, then after 10 seconds Clear method should be called which will clear all MudTextFields. So how can I apply timer for 10 seconds to call Clear method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Task.Delay()` [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0) where you can pass an `int` parameter which is time in milliseconds. So for a 10 seconds delay it would be`await Task.Delay(10000)`.

I think you should also include a cancellation token so that if the method is called before one of the delays is finished it will cancel the previous delay and start from 0 again, otherwise it will clear multiple times on separate timers.

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
async Task ClearAfterDelay(string inputValue)
{
    try
    {
        _cts.Cancel(); 
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
        //assign the values to the TextFields
        await Task.Delay(10000,_cts.Token);
        //clear the values of the TextFields
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // for logic if task cancelled prematurely
    }

}
```

I've setup a [MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEGHvOFmgAHAFwIP) **Note** the snippet is shortened to show only 2 sec delay.

Also, you might or might not need to call a `StateHasChanged()` After the delay is finished **and** the inputs are cleared.